# Regular Expression(Ruby): match non-word, but exclude spaces

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

`^(?=(.*\d){4,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?!\s)(?=.*\W{2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,}).{12,14}$`

The RegExp above is trying to:

- match at least 4 digits - `(?=(.*\d){4,})`
- match exactly 3 upper case letters - `(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})`
- don't match spaces - `(?!\s)`
- match at least 2 non-word characters - `(?=.*\W{2,})`
- match at least 2 lower - `(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})`
- string must be between 12 and 14 in length - `.{12,14}`

But I am having a challenge getting this to avoid matching spaces.  It seems like because \W also includes spaces, my preceding negative look-ahead on spaces is being ignored.

*For example:*

- `b4A@Ac33*8Pd` -- should match
- `b4A@Ac3 3*8Pd` -- should not match

[rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/KnxAIY5KTF)

Edited to provide further clarification:

Basically, I am trying to avoid having to spell out all the characters in the POSIX [:punct:] class ie `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_\`{|}~-` .. that is why I had a need to use \W .. But I would also want to exclude spaces

I can use a second pair of eyes, and more experienced suggestions here ..

Edited again, to correct mix-ups in counts specified in sub-patterns, as pointed out in the accepted answer below.

Comment: Could you add a test which should match but doesn't, or a text which shouldn't match but does?

Comment: I'm with @UriAgassi - it makes asker's life easier

Comment: Yeah, I agree .. I also got the letter count mixed up.  Have edited now.  Thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is not with `\W` it is with `.*` - remove the `(?=.*\W{1,})` and see...

Comment: If I remove just the `.*` to leave `(?=\W{1,})` none of the strings are matched.  If I remove the entire look-ahead sub-pattern of `(?=.*\W{1,})`, both of them still match .. Its like the `(?!\s)` has no effect at all (with or without the \W sub-pattern) .. The only way the space sub-pattern has an impact is when I change it to `(?!.*\s)` but surprisingly enough it fails to match either string.  My understanding of how negative look-ahead works is being challenged here

Comment: Is your rubular link wrong? You are talking about `\W{1,}`, while the rubular link regex is `\W{1}`, plus other differencies

Comment: @mdesantis, you are right .. too many edits.  Link and letter count fixed now.

Comment: It seems to me that `(?!\s)` doesn't work: http://www.rubular.com/r/e8cEKt3cEn I don't know why, it should for me... you could try to ask for a regex which excludes whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using dot `.`, use non spaces `\S`:

```
^(?=(.*\d){3,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=.*\W{1,})(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})\S{12,14}$
//                                                  here ___^^
```

And is this a typo `match at least 4 digits - (?=(.*\d){3,})`,
it should be:

```
match at least 3 digits - (?=(.*\d){3,})
```

or

```
match at least 4 digits - (?=(.*\d){4,})
```

Same for other counts.

Comment: Yeah, typos and mix-ups.  Basically, I am working with different patterns for different things, and got the counts all mixed up but the concept/idea is the same.  Your suggestion to match for non-space at the end certainly works .. I have also found that changing from `(?!\s)` to `(?!.* .*)` in my original pattern works.

Comment: Generally, it seems like the use of character classes confuses the look-aheads in regexp engine in ruby < 2 .. for instance `\W{n}` seems to be counting the unseen newline character '\n' at the end of the string

Comment: I am still struggling to understand why changing from `(?\s)` to `(?!.* .*)` in my original pattern works BUT `(?!.*\s.*)` does not work just the same way

Comment: @ChuxUzoeto: `(?!\s)` doesn't work because it searches a non-space at first position, that's why `(?!.* .*)` works. For me `(?!.*\s.*)` works also.

Comment: I did move the sub-pattern `(?!\s)` around .. and tested it even at the first position (see [rubular-1](http://www.rubular.com/r/T2VIbYCKQ2)).  I have again tested against `(?!.*\s.*)` and it is still failing to match either string (see [rubular-2](http://www.rubular.com/r/2EYcfImpCr)) .. whereas `(?!.* .*)` does the right thing and matches the first string.  Weird and unexpected.